# Longest English word without a vowel sound

Tags: vowels, sounds

I am not an English student, by discipline I am physicist, so am asking this question in innocence.

I searched Google for the longest word without a vowel sound and I got these results:

> The longest common word without any of the five vowels is RHYTHMS, 
>   but there are longer  rare words: SYMPHYSY, NYMPHLY, GYPSYRY, GYPSYFY

However, English students don't agree: they say there is an `\i-sound\` and `\schwa\` in the word RHYTHM.

I am confused: what should I believe, the internet or my English university students?

Comment: It is more logical to allow _y_ as an English vowel when it does the same job as the traditional 5 - thus in _sky_, but not in _yell_. In the odd loan-word from Welsh, _w_ is a seventh vowel (eg _cwm_). There is not always one syllable for every vowel in a word, but it is extremely rare for there to be a syllable without a corresponding vowel; I'd say _rhythm_ is a very strange word.

Comment: Hmmmmmmmmmm... I wonder what that word might be ;-)

Comment: By the way, while *internet* is a common noun, *the Internet* is a proper noun, so it should be capitalised. The same is true for *the Web*.

Comment: The English word "rng" (which means a ring without identity) contains no vowels. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rng_(algebra).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All the words you mention have vowel sounds. I can think of no English word that doesn't have vowel sounds, except something like *Mmm*.

Comment: So for the longest such word, just repeatedly add an *m* :)

Comment: There's also "Hmm..."

Comment: @RandolfRichardson: Yes, and no doubt several others.

Comment: @Barrie England:  Mmm hmm.  ;-)

Comment: My dictionary has the word: **phpht**

Comment: @GEdgar: Impressive. Which dictionary, what's the definition, and how does it appear in phonetic symbols?

Comment: **phpht** (Interjection, Used to signify mild annoyance or disagreement) ... Wiktionary http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/phpht does say it is rare, and provides 4 quotations ... Note it is also found as short for "phenolphthalein" although written as "PhPht."

Comment: @GEdgar: Then it's of a kind with 'Mmm'.

Comment: @GEdgar: Oh. Wiktionary. Yeah, I'm gonna start entering 'words' there myself.

Comment: @Mitch: I could have cited Collins English Dictionary, but it has no quotations, and does not say *phpht* is rare.

Comment: @GEdgar: I think they spelled it wrong.

Comment: The most important use of words being in games of Scrabble, obviously their dictionary trumps all the others. They allow _sh_, _ch_, and _brrr_ (in some versions). If you've a lot of vowels, _euouea_ may be useful.

Comment: It's not that there just are no English words that lack a vowel sound; you can't have a syllable without a vowel in any language, except languages that are made up of clicks. Consonants are percussive, like a drum hit, while vowels are notes, like a violin plays. Only the later can be held for variable lengths of time. Vowels are the notes that join the percussive consonants, and are what make syllables pronounceable, without resorting to a broken sequence of clicks.

Comment: @CarlSmith There are no languages that are made up of clicks. All languages that have click phonemes also have other phonemes. Whether or not you can have a syllable without a vowel depends on your definition of a syllable – sadly, as with words, there is no single, universal definition. There are certainly languages which have words with no vowel sounds in them; Nuxalk is probably the bet-known example, with words like _ḱx_ ‘see’ or _qʷt_ ‘bent’.

Comment: I didn't say there are languages that are made of clicks. I was explaining that vowels allow constants (which are percussive) to be joined together, and pointed out that this is nothing to do with English specifically by noting that the alternative would be a language of "clicks" (meaning the sounds that constants make if you remove any vowel sound, which was clear if you read the whole comment).

Answer (score 13):

Debatable but there is a [list on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Words_without_vowels#Words_without_vowel_sounds) which seems to classify these based on dialect

> Rhotic dialects, such as in Canada and the United States, have many
>   words such as **bird, learn, girl, church, worst**, which some
>   phoneticians analyze as having no vowels, only a syllabic consonant,
>   [ɹ̩]. However, others analyze these words instead as having a rhotic
>   vowel, [ɝ]. The difference may be partially one of dialect.
>
> There are a few such words which are disyllabic, like **cursor, curtain**,
>   and **turtle**: [ˈkɹ̩sɹ̩], [ˈkɹ̩tn̩] and [ˈtɹ̩tl̩] (or [ˈkɝːsɚ],
>   [ˈkɝːtən], and [ˈtɝːtəl]), and even a few which are trisyllabic, such
>   as **purpler** [ˈpɹ̩.pl̩.ɹ̩], **hurdler** [ˈhɹ̩.dl̩.ɹ̩], **burglar**
>   [ˈbɹ̩.ɡl̩.ɹ̩], **gurgler** [ˈɡɹ̩.ɡl̩.ɹ̩], **certainer** [ˈsɹ̩.tn̩.ɹ̩], and
>   **Ur-turtle** [ˈɹ̩.tɹ̩.tl̩]. The words **wyrm** and **myrrh** contain neither a
>   vowel letter nor a vowel sound in these dialects: [ˈwɹ̩m], [ˈmɹ̩] (or
>   [ˈwɝːm], [ˈmɝː]).

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It's exactly answering this question. If you disagree with the "some phoneticians", take it up with them. :-)

Comment: I think certain pronunciations of *Worcestershire* would fall into this category.

Comment: This is useful, although I find it exceedingly silly to say that "y" is not a "vowel letter" in *wyrm* and *myrrh.*

Comment: @AndrewVit In Worcestershire they say ['wʊstəʃə]. Is the FOOT vowel to be deemed not a vowel? So is "cookbooks" vowelless?

Answer (score 0):

It is true that almost all English words have at least one vowel sound. The only exception (other than Hmmm, zzz, etc.) that I know is [rng](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rng_(algebra)). A rng is an algebraic structure satisfying the same properties as a [ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)), without assuming the existence of a multiplicative identity. In short, a rng is like a ring without i (the identity element); which hopefully explains its vowelless spelling.

Comment: The best pronunciation I can come up with for "rng" is [ɹəŋ]. English phonology requires an utterance to consist of syllables, a syllable to have a nucleus, and that nucleus to be some sort of vowel. Any exception must cheat in some way, e.g. by the supposed word being not a word but some paralinguistic representation of some noise (e.g. Barrie's *Mmm*), or by its pronunciation being deemed vowelless by some analysis where the NURSE vowel and/or the COMMA vowel are not deemed to be vowels (as in Wikipedia's examples quoted by shinynewbike).