# Are "mmm" and "hmm" the only words in the English language without vowel letters?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary, orthography, consonants

Somebody told me that "[hmm](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/hmm?s=t)" and "[mmm](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/mmm?s=t)" are the only words in the English language without a vowel. Is that true?

If not, please provide counterexamples.

No acronyms please.

I am not looking for words that *sound* as if they have no vowels ([that's already answered here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48346/longest-english-word-without-a-vowel-sound)), but whole words that have no vowels in their *spelling* or consonants used as vowels as such as 'y'.

Some syllables have no vowels, and [that is already answered here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24005/are-there-any-other-english-syllables-without-vowels-besides-thm?rq=1), but I want whole words.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_words_without_vowels

Comment: Tsk, tsk, who told you that?

Comment: The [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48346/longest-english-word-without-a-vowel-sound) you linked to cited *rhythms*, a word with no vowels in its spelling. Please [edit] your question to explain why this doesn't answer your question, and what you mean instead by "no vowels in their *spelling*".

Comment: Did you google this?  It's just that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_words_without_vowels which links to https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_words_without_vowels

Comment: This question does not appear to be about English language and usage within the scope defined in the help center. It is a request for resources, and, like 'What words in English have more than a single pair of double letters', a request for trivia. It is also lacking in research (and is general reference).

Comment: @Lawrence No; **y** is the vowel usage in _rhythm_,  _truly_ and _sky_ (as opposed to the half-vowel in say _yellow_). 'W' is a vowel in the now English word _cwm_.

Comment: The definition of the word 'word' is contentious. 'hmm' and 'mmm' are very near the border. (I consider them on the other side of wordness). Whatever it is, the rules are unclear. If 'mmm' is a word, then why isn't 'mmmm' and 'mmmmm' etc?

Comment: @Mitch What is "the other side of wordness"? Do you mean a collection of letters that are widely used as a word, but which is not a word? "Ghoti" comes to mind as an obvious example since it is widely used, but is not a word. Or do you mean a collection of letters with no definition? "Mmm" has a definition in the dictionary, but "mmmm" does not.

Comment: @RichS Why isn't 'mmmm' in the dictionary? Can you use 'mmm' in  sentence? How does 'mmm' fit the idea of 'word'? (a dictionary definition is a start but is not everything)

Answer (score 2):

**Tsk** tsk, what research was done before posting this question :)

Refs
[Tsk  tsk (urban dic.)](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=tsk%20tsk) and 
[nGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=tsk%2C%20shhh%20&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctsk%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshhh%3B%2Cc0).

And for further background illumination, [wiktionary...:English_words_without_vowels](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_words_without_vowels)

Thanks for the constructive feedback @Mari-Lou A

Comment: Grrr was gonna answer that!

Comment: LMGTFY answers are not acceptable on ELU. Like the questions prompting them.

Comment: Thank you @EdwinAshworth, for introducing me to the (hitherto unknown to me) category of LMGTFY.

Answer (score 1):

Also ***[zzz](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/zzz):***
(exclamation UK ​)
​

> used in a picture or a piece of writing to represent the noise that people make when they are sleeping.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

From Google Books: [zzz](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=zzz&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Czzz%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 1):

(Note: an update to the question removed the basis for the previous version of this answer. The current version notes that the question as posed is unanswerable.)

Strictly speaking, [vowels](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/vowel) are either speech sounds or letters representing them. It therefore doesn't make sense to talk about words that "have no vowels in their spelling" as a matter distinct from "words that sound as if they have no vowels".

So in words such as "bird", [pronounced in a rhotic dialect](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/48349/142322), the written 'i' isn't pronounced and therefore doesn't count as a vowel. Conversely, in words such as "my", the 'y' is pronounced as a vowel and therefore does count as a vowel.

Other words, such as [*hmm*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hmm) and [*pfft/pfftt*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pfft), have dictionary entries and contain no vowels in their spelling, but they also have no vowels in their pronunciation. Such words rely on 'sustained' consonants such as *f*, *m* and *n*.

I conclude that there aren't any words that contain no vowels in their spelling which don't *also* sound as if they have no vowels in their pronunciation.

Comment: You do realize the letter Y has vowel uses, including in the very specific examples you are giving, right?

Comment: @PierreArlaud It's more of an attempt at humour. Besides, the OP wanted something without *written* vowels, not something without vowel *sounds*. I've edited to explain.

Comment: @PierreArlaud Answer rehashed.

Answer (score -3):

Rhythm has no vowels.

There's also lots of examples for shorter words like why, cry, spy, shy, dry and fly.

Comment: Opinion, and almost certainly not mainstream. And unsupported. See [Colin Fine's much more scholarly article](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10458/when-is-y-a-vowel).